# hook_page_alter in Drupal 8

Tags: 8

I am trying to append a twig template on every page .
In drupal 7, we basically append it using `hook_page_alter`

```
      function hook_page_alter(&$page) { 
      $page['page_bottom']['devel']= array( 
            '#type' => 'markup', 
            '#markup' => '<div style="clear:both;">' . theme('TEST') . '</div>', );  //add test template on every page at bottom position
 }
```

but in drupal 8 there is no `hook_page_alter` i think.

How to do this??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

hook_page_alter in Drupal 8:

According to the change record [Added hook_page_attachments(_alter)() and removed hook_page_build/alter()](https://www.drupal.org/node/2357755) you should use [hook_page_bottom](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_bottom/8.2.x):

```
function hook_page_bottom(array &$page_bottom) {
  $page_bottom['mymodule'] = ['#markup' => 'This is the bottom.'];
}
```

You have another issue, theme() is no longer available. But this is another question as it is unclear what you are trying to do with it. Probably you should use the template in a render array `$page_bottom['mymodule'] = ['#theme' => 'TEST'];`.

In D8 all page elements are in blocks now. The best approach would be to provide the extra content in a custom block and place it in the block layout in the bottom of the page. See comment from @Kevin.

Comment: It might be easier to do a custom block, or just write the HTML in the theme that should show everywhere (although I would probably not do that). It's hard to say without knowing what/why this is needed.

Comment: @Kevin, I agree. Answer is about the question in the title, but I should add, that D8 is all about blocks.